# How to create time series visualisation in power BI

Tags: powerbi

[image]

I'm new to Power BI online but trying to create a time-series chart with sum of sales by month, year and split by country. My result is:

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With the Line chart visual selected put the Date hierarchy on the X-axis, Sales on the Y-axis and Country on the Legend field.

Comment: At the moment the chart reports count. How do I achieve sum?